# List of lists in R: Show only all integer columns

Tags: r, list, integer, sublist

Hi Stack Overflow Community,

I've invested now a few hours but I didn't find the answer. I have a `list` of 200 sublists in R. Each contains a character column and an integer column named `FREQUENCY`. My goal is to show only the integer columns. I've tested the function manually with the `list`-function and the first two sublists and it works:

```
mydata <- list(Name1[[1]]$FREQUENCY, Name1[[2]]FREQUENCY)
```

Now to my question: How is it possible to take all 200 sublists with one command. I need the `list`-function in this process, because I have to sum each `FREQUENCY` sublist in a next step:

```
lapply(mydata, sum)
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Do you mean `lst <- lapply(Name1, function(x) x$FREQUENCY)`?

Comment: if they are columns it means it's a list of data.frames, not a list of lists right ?

Comment: Hi Maurice, thank you for your response. Moody's second command is the one I've searched for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a base solution (if i understand properly):

```
your_list <- list(data.frame(a="hello",b=1),
                  data.frame(c="world",d=1))
# [[1]]
#       a b
# 1 hello 1
# 
# [[2]]
#       c d
# 1 world 1

lapply(your_list,function(x) x[,sapply(x,is.numeric),drop=FALSE])
# [[1]]
#   b
# 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
#   d
# 1 1
```

Comment: Awesome! You did it! Thank you very much Moody!